# Pandas GroupBy - How to extract seconds from DateTime with diff() excluding weekends

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to calculate the difference between two dates in seconds excluding weekends and holidays in a groupby data-frame.I am able to calculate diff() but I am unable to exclude weekends from it.

I have an "event_dattim " columns as timestamp as str which I have converted to datetim as :

```
df['event_dattim'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['event_dattim'], format=r'%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S.%f')
```

I can get the total diff in seconds using :

```
 df2['difference'] = df2.groupby (['key_date','key_time','key_milsec','recordcd','crnode'])     ['event_dattim'].diff().dt.total_seconds()
```

but this does not exclude any weekends and holidays. I have tried multiple things but failed getting different errors. 
The closest I have come is using:

```
df1 = df.groupby(by=['key_date','key_time','key_milsec','recordcd','crnode'])['event_dattim'].apply(lambda x:office_time_between(x.min(),x.max())).reset_index(drop=True).
df['working seconds']= df / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
```

but this just takes the max and min values not the difference between rows.

office_time_between is the function I have for made calculating working seconds.

```
def clamp(t, start, end):
   "Return `t` clamped to the range [`start`, `end`]."
   return max(start, min(end, t))

def day_part(t):
   "Return timedelta between midnight and `t`."
    return t - t.replace(hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0)

def office_time_between(a, b, start = timedelta(hours = 0),
                    stop = timedelta(hours = 24)):
"""
    Return the total office time between `a` and `b` as a timedelta
    object. Office time consists of weekdays from `start` to `stop`
    (default: 00:00 to 24:00).
"""
    zero = timedelta(0)
    assert(zero <= start <= stop <= timedelta(1))
    office_day = stop - start
    days = (b - a).days + 1   #changed here from (.day )
    weeks = days // 7
    extra = (max(0, 5 - a.weekday()) + min(5, 1 + b.weekday())) % 5
    weekdays = weeks * 5 + extra
    total = office_day * weekdays
    if a.weekday() < 5:
        total -= clamp(day_part(a) - start, zero, office_day)
    if b.weekday() < 5:
        total -= clamp(stop - day_part(b), zero, office_day)
    return total.
```

```html
key_date key_time key_milsec recordcd crnode event_dattim
6/1/2019 00.00.05 0 T 1 2019-05-31-11.00.05.731871
6/1/2019 00.00.24 430500 T 1 2019-06-01-00.00.24.552302
6/1/2019 00.00.24 430500 T 1 2019-06-04-02.54.56.658875
6/1/2019 00.00.24 430500 T 1 2019-06-04-10.35.54.820187
6/1/2019 00.00.24 430500 T 1 2019-06-04-10.37.53.829744
6/1/2019 00.00.27 453440 T 1 2019-06-01-00.00.27.553880
6/1/2019 00.00.27 453440 T 1 2019-06-04-02.54.56.668795
6/1/2019 00.00.27 453440 T 1 2019-06-04-07.40.31.163718
6/1/2019 00.00.27 453440 T 1 2019-06-04-07.41.45.995590
6/1/2019 00.00.27 453440 T 1 2019-06-05-02.52.35.476701
6/1/2019 00.00.27 453440 T 1 2019-06-05-12.47.31.263512
6/1/2019 00.00.31 70480 T 1 2019-06-01-00.00.31.149815
6/1/2019 00.00.31 70480 T 1 2019-06-04-02.54.56.676816
6/1/2019 00.00.31 70480 T 1 2019-06-04-10.35.40.414527
```